# MySQL text search example

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called table1 with 3 columns, a, b, and c.

`b` is varchar(600), say, and I wish to return the int from column `a`, say.

Let's assume the term I am looking for is "This term".

What would a single complete example be with the basic syntax required to search for this phrase as above in `b` and return the respective `a` in MySQL as the Internet is totally unclear on this?

Basically, what would the mysql_query string look like for a text search?

Comment: Are you asking about a [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is.  The mysql pages are incredibly difficult to read for a beginner.  What is the difference?

Comment: Full-text searching involves creating special fulltext indexes and using appropriate syntax (MATCH) to search text more efficiently. See the link in my first comment for more information.

Comment: But using the fulltext index means only MyISAM table type correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will look for 'This term' anywhere in b

```
SELECT a FROM table1 WHERE b LIKE('%This term%')
```

You could also just find records that start with 'This term'

```
SELECT a FROM table1 WHERE b LIKE('This term%')
```

The % operator is the wildcard in the like condition.

Comment: No need for parentheses - LIKE is an operator, not a function.

Comment: I think it makes it easier to read, but you are correct you don't need it.

Answer (score 6):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a FROM sometable WHERE b LIKE '%This term%'");
```

Depending on what you plan to do, [MySQL Fulltext Indices](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) might be interesting for you.

Comment: +1 cause you are the only one so far who noticed this was for MySQL and PHP :)

Comment: Is the table name missing here or is it meant to be absent?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE b LIKE '%This term%'
```

Comment: You need to include wildcards, otherwise what you've written is equivalent to `...WHERE b = 'This term'`

Comment: in case if "b" is huge and its needed to spot a presence of 'This temp' - I agree.